# Visual Studio 2015 - Debug with HTTP connection problems

Tags: http, twitter, visual-studio-2015, connect, linq-to-twitter

I have a program (console application) that makes use of LinqToTwitter to read some tweets. When I debug the program I get an error "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred in a submission".

Message = An error occurred while sending the request.
Message = The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected send error occurred.

If I build the program, I can run the program without any problems. I already researched and can't find the problem. Does it have to do with TLS 1.2? How do I set up in Visual Studio? I use VS 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that you mention TLS 1.2 and you're using an older version of Visual Studio, it makes sense. Add this to your `Main` procedure:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
```

Twitter switched to TLS 1.2 a while ago.

Comment: Thank you! But, I still have doubts: my application is written in VB.net, when I saw your answer, I thought of putting this parameter in app.config, but I didn't find the right place, because within the startup only supportedRuntime and requiredRuntime parameters are recognized. I researched the internet about where to put this parameter and I was also not lucky to find out. Where should I put this parameter?

Comment: It isn't a parameter, it's code. I updated the code to explain that this can be in your Main procedure and removed the semi-colon (VB).

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly, now I can debug the program without abend.

By the way, in the other question, I couldn't mark your answer as a solution, I think it was because it came as a comment and not an answer!

Comment: I created an answer over there that refers to this one - assuming they're the same issue.